# SQL Select Specific Records based on Text Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, union

I have a table of Countries....

```
CountryID     CountryCode    CountryName
1              AF             Afghanistan
2              AX             ALAND ISLANDS
3              AL             Albania
4              DZ             Algeria etc.
```

I am going to use this to populate a drop down menu on a web page. What I would like is to be able to have the four countries below appear first, then have the entire list appear below these four in ASC order.

```
CountryID    CountryCode     CountryName
236            US             United States
40             CA             Canada
76             FR             France
235            UK             United Kingdom
```

I have tried various approaches but not gotten it yet.

```
SELECT *
From [dbo].[tblCountries]
WHERE CountryID IN (236,40,76,235)
ORDER BY CountryName asc
```

This gives me the 4 countries I want, but does not allow me to display the another below them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a UNION to get the result, you can use a CASE expression in an ORDER BY:

```
select [CountryID], [CountryCode], [CountryName]
from tblCountries
order by
  case [CountryID]
    when 236 then 1
    when 40 then 2
    when 76 then 3
    when 235 then 4
    else 5
  end, [CountryName];
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78061/3)